# How not to hide spaces in hidden word, how to check for more than one letter, and ignore case of letters

Tags: java

I am working on a Hidden Phrase Game. I solved my other two issues and want to thank those that helped me. However, the final problem I am having is "when the program checks the hidden word for letters all the matching letters are filled in, regardless of case". Example, if you enter f, it should fill in f and F. Not sure how to do this.

```java
package main;
import java.util.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int choice;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        Player player = new Player();
        player.setName(name);
        
        do 
        {
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Hidden Word Game!");

            game(player);
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again?\n" +
                    "1: Yes\n" +
                    "2: No");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
        } while (choice != 2);
    }
    
    public static void game(Player player) 
    {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String[] wordList = new String[] {"cruise ship", "soft drink", "National Football League", "New York", "little girl"};
        String randomWord = wordList[(int)(Math.random() * wordList.length)];

        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < randomWord.length(); i++) 
            {
                if (randomWord.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    word.append(' ');
                } else {
                    word.append('*');
                }
            }

        char[] hiddenWord = randomWord.toCharArray();

        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        while(true) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Secrect Word :" + word);
                    System.out.print("Guess one or more letters : ");
                    player.setAttempts();
                    boolean correct = false;

                    char [] guess = input.nextLine().toCharArray();

                    for(int i = 0 ; i < hiddenWord.length; i++) 
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < guess.length; j++)
                            {
                                if (guess[j] == hiddenWord[i]) 
                                {
                                    word.setCharAt(i, guess[j]);
                                    correct = true;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    if (!correct) 
                        {
                            System.out.println("You chose incorrect");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("You chose correct");
                        }

                    System.out.println("--------------------");

                    if (randomWord.equals(word.toString())) 
                        {
                            System.out.println("Congratulations " + player.getName() + " You Guessed The Hidden Word: " + randomWord);
                            System.out.println("It took you " + player.getAttempts() + " attempts.");                            
                            break;
                        }
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you're creating `word`, check whether the ith letter of `randomword` is a space.

Comment: Don't just take the first letter of `guess` -- use a loop over its letters.

Comment: And look at `Character.toLowerCase(char)`.

Comment: @tgdavies how do I check for the space when I am creating the word

Comment: There are three parts to that: using a space literal, getting the ith character of `randomWord`, and comparing them. Which are you having trouble with?

Comment: @tgdavies how do you suggest I loop over the letters of guess?

Comment: You can do that the same way you loop over the letters of `randomWord`, except that you access each character via an array index instead of `charAt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check the space character and add it to the word.

```
StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < randomWord.length(); i++) {
        if (randomWord.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            word.append(' ');
        } else {
            word.append('*');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess i've been looking at it so long, I didn't even think of that. It makes perferct sense now. Thank you